Как залогиниться на сайт Python Requests?
Впервые пытаюсь писать код в данном направлении.
Есть сайт, в него нужно залогиниться.
При входе на страничку в строке сразу появляется токен вида
https://api.sitename.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=ItemSharingWebAdmin&state=NBb4Y5u329EQ3oqQqesPQdxoTPjZxd5WVaygxw82zyQxF&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.sitename.com%2Fdashboard%2Fmonitoring&scope=openid%20profile

Имеется логин и пароль, как залогиниться?
Токен при каждом обновлении страницы разный. Его нужно каждый раз подтягивать.

во-первых, я не вижу никакого токена в приведенном URL, во-вторых, где ваш код, который вы впервые пытаетесь написать?
